# How to write a function that returns the sum of the numbers with biggest absolute values in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In 2018, on a test about databases (which I have failed multiple times) at my university, they had this task:

> Napisati T-SQL funkciju koja prima 3 realna broja, te kao rezultat vraća onaj broj koji ima najveću apsolutnu vrijednost. Ako slučajno istu najveću apsolutnu vrijednost imaju dva ili tri broja potrebno je vratiti zbroj tih brojeva.

That is:

> Write a T-SQL function that accepts 3 real numbers, and as a result it returns the number that has the biggest absolute value. If accidentally the same biggest absolute value is got by two or three numbers it is necessary to return the sum of those numbers.

How would you solve that?

Here is my attempt, I do not know if it is correct nor how to actually test it on my computer:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION max_abs3(@x, @y, @z DECIMAL) RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
    IF ABS(@x)=ABS(@y) AND ABS(@y)=ABS(@z)
    BEGIN
        RETURN @x+@y+@z;
    END;
    IF ABS(@x)=ABS(@y) AND ABS(@x)>ABS(@z)
    BEGIN
        RETURN @x+@y;
    END;
    IF ABS(@x)=ABS(@z) AND ABS(@x)>ABS(@y)
    BEGIN
        RETURN @x+@z;
    END;
    IF ABS(@y)=ABS(@z) AND ABS(@y)>ABS(@x)
    BEGIN
        RETURN @y+@z;
    END;
    IF ABS(@x)>ABS(@y) AND ABS(@x)>ABS(@z)
    BEGIN
        RETURN @x;
    END;
    IF ABS(@y)>ABS(@z) AND ABS(@y)>ABS(@x)
        RETURN @y;
    END;
    RETURN @z;
END;
```

I have only managed to install SQLite on my computer, and it apparently does not support custom SQL functions.

Comment: If the absolute numbers are the same, are the absolute values to be added together, or the values? If, for example, the values were `-10`, `5`, and `10` would the result be `0` (`-10 + 10`) +or `20` (`ABS(-10) + ABS(10)`)?

Comment: @Larnu If I correctly understand the task, the result should be `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "in 2018" you mean the solution must of worked in 2018 (so SQL Server 2017 or prior), then you could use a `VALUES` clause to make your values into a dataset, and then check to see if the value is the maximum value and then aggregate.

As you need to do this yourself, this here's what the logic inside the function would look like: I leave you to put this appropriately into a `FUNCTION` (ideally an inline table value function):

```sql
SELECT SUM(V.R)
FROM (VALUES(@x),(@y),(@z))V(R)
WHERE ABS(V.R) = (SELECT MAX(sq.R)
                  FROM (VALUES(@x),(@y),(@z))sq(R));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69bc1b8b527cef988770d4ea9f8e00fd)

In SQL Server 2022 there is a new function, `GREATEST` which would look like this:

```sql
WITH V AS(
    SELECT R
    FROM (VALUES(@x),(@y),(@z))V(R))
SELECT SUM(R)
FROM V
WHERE ABS(V.R) = GREATEST(@x,@y,@z);
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way, is my attempt correct?

Comment: Your attempt (at least for the function) has syntax errors, @FlatAssembler .